# Working with podio api, i get a DateTime object and cant access its values

Tags: php, date, datetime, podio

i make an API call for Podio, to get active space members. One of the fields that returns is `last_seen_on`, which is a `DateTime` Object.

When i `print_r()` it looks like:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2013-11-02 22:47:09
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

The issue is when I get the `date` or `timezone_type` or `timezone` by doing `$object[date]`, or `$object->date` it throws an error.

Now i am not sure if this has something to do with php DateTime class, if so.. how do I use that object with that class?

Comment: @BenFortune make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a datetime instance, you can return the date with the following. Or however you want, in accordance to the documentation.

```
echo $object->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Link to documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: that's also what i suspected and i tried that but did not work before - maybe i did something wrong will try again. Yap .. you are correct